# Powershell saving as csv file

Tags: csv, powershell

Good day!

I am trying to get the opened applications that you can see on the taskbar, the computers' IP address and its username. After which, I would save it in a text file with the values separated by commas. Now, I want everything to be saved in the text file but in my set of codes, the results from `Get-process` are the only ones that are saved on the text file. How can I include the IP address and the username saved together with the results from `Get-process` on the same text file.

Here is my code:

```
$savepath = "C:\Users\$([Environment]::UserName)\Desktop\apps\runningapps.txt"

Get-process | where {$_.mainwindowtitle.length -ne 0} | select name, mainwindowtitle|  Export-Csv $savepath -notype
Get-WMIObject -class Win32_ComputerSystem | select username| Export-Csv $savepath -append -notype
Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration |
    Where { $_.IPAddress } | # filter the objects where an address actually exists
    Select -Expand IPAddress | # retrieve only the property *value*
    Where { $_ -notlike "*:*" }|Export-Csv $savepath -append -notype
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue is because the three objects you are exporting have different attributes, you are having the trouble?

If you really want to put it all on one file, then you could

```
ConvertTo-Csv -notype | Add-Content $savepath
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply sir. I'm really new to this so umm If I may ask, where am i going to place this?

Comment: replace your Export-Csv with that snippet.  It is "exporting" in two steps, first converting to a CSV string, then adding that to your file